# Need help writing a java program that adds multiple digits?

Tags: java

I am trying to write this java program that asks a user for a number and counts the number of digits a number has and multiplies each digit to it's decimal value. For example I enter 546: The program should say this number has 3 digits and should multiply:
        5*100=500
4*10=40
1*6=6

So far this is my code:  The problems I am having with this code is that it's not counting the right amount of digits. If I enter 545 it says there is only one digit, and when it goes to divides it doesn't give the right answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
        n /= 10;
        for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
            n /= 10;
            System.out.println((n%100000) / 10000);
            System.out.println((n%10000) / 1000);                 
            System.out.println((n%1000) / 100);
            System.out.println((n%100) / 10);
            System.out.println(n%10);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of digits: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see how when you call nextInt() it would read 545 as a single integer with a value of 545. You want to find the length of the input (read as a string maybe), and then separate out: If there are 3 digits, the first one is hundreds, 2nd is tens and 3rd is ones.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of digits in user entered value, you can get the value and check the length of the value after converting it to String. This will give you the exact length of the digit.

For example, if variable "uservalue" in the below snippet is user entered value, the output after executing the snippet, it prints the numberOfDigit as"3".

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    int uservalue=546;
    int numberOfDigit=0;
    String userValueinStr=String.valueOf(uservalue);
    numberOfDigit=userValueinStr.length();
    System.out.println("Number of digits in user entered value is::"+numberOfDigit );

    //Now as you got the no. of digits, you can go ahead and add the your logic of   multiplication
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a set of nested for loops that both call n /= 10. It is easier to see if you indent everything:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
     int n = keyboard.nextInt();
     int i;
     for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
         n /= 10;

         for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
             n /= 10;
             System.out.println((n%100000) / 10000);
             System.out.println((n%10000) / 1000);                 
             System.out.println((n%1000) / 100);
             System.out.println((n%100) / 10);
             System.out.println(n%10);
         }
         System.out.println("Number of digits: " + i);
     }
 }
```

After removing this, the code seems to work as intended, and tells you that 545 does, in fact have 3 digits. Here is the revised code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    int i;

    for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
        n /= 10;
        System.out.println((n%100000) / 10000);
        System.out.println((n%10000) / 1000);                 
        System.out.println((n%1000) / 100);
        System.out.println((n%100) / 10);
        System.out.println(n%10);
    }

    System.out.println("Number of digits: " + i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you trying to do the same task, by using arbitrary values. Instead try to incorporate some generic sort of an algorithm. Somethingy on the lines of this posted example:

```
public class CountDigits {

    private void performTask () {
        int number = 546;
        int temp = number;
        int digit = 0;
        int counter = 1;
        while ( temp != 0 ) {
            digit = temp % 10;
            System.out.println ( digit + " * " + getMultiplier ( counter ) + " = " + ( digit * getMultiplier ( counter ) ) );
            ++counter;
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }

    private int getMultiplier ( int power ) {
        int value = 1;
        for ( int i = 1; i < power; ++i ) {
            value *= 10;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        new CountDigits ().performTask ();
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
C:\Mine\java\bin>java CountDigits
9 * 1 = 9
1 * 10 = 10
1 * 100 = 100
1 * 1000 = 1000


C:\Mine\java\bin>java CountDigits
6 * 1 = 6
4 * 10 = 40
5 * 100 = 500
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 546;
for( int i = 0, dig = (int) Math.log10( n ) + 1; i < dig; ++i )
{
    int mult = (int) Math.pow( 10, dig - i - 1 );
    int a = (n / mult) % 10;
    System.out.println( a + " * " + mult + " = " + (a * mult) );
}
```

Results in:

```
5 * 100 = 500
4 * 10 = 40
6 * 1 = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 546;
int exponent = (int) (Math.log10(n));

for (int i = exponent; i >= 0; i--) {
    int displayNum = (n / (int) Math.pow(10, i)) * (int) Math.pow(10, i);
    System.out.println(displayNum);
    n = n - displayNum;
}
```

outputs

```
System.out﹕ 500
System.out﹕ 40
System.out﹕ 6
```